Nonsingularity about the controlability gramian
I am recently learning Linear system theory and design by Chen (1999 edition), and on page 146 he said that every entry of $W_c(t)$ is analytic of $t$, where $W_c(t)$ is the control gramian 
$W_c(t)=\int_0^t{e^{A\tau}BB'e^{A'\tau}}d\tau$ 
"if $W_c$ is nonsingular for some $t$, then it is nonsingular for all $t$."
I don't know the rationale behind this, can someone tell me? The control gramian is positive semidefinite and analytic, but I think this is not enough to support the conculsion.
Besides, in page 107, there is a claim that assume that if the fundamental matrix is singular at $t_1$, then it is singular at all $t$, why?
Thank you for helping!

Well $W_c(t)$ is obviously always singular at $t=0$, regardless of $(A,B)$.

Let $n$ denote the size of $A$ and suppose that $B$ has shape $n \times m$. I will use the notation $W_c(t; A,B)$ to include $A,B$ as possibly changeable parameters. To prove that statement regarding the controllability grammian, it suffices to note the following:

The controllability grammian $W_c(1;A,B)$ is invertible if and only if the standard controllability matrix
$$
\mathcal C(A,B) = [B\ \ AB\ \ \cdots \ \ A^{n-1}B]
$$
has full rank.
For any scalar $k > 0$, $\mathcal C(kA,B)$ has the same rank as $\mathcal C(A,B)$, since
$$
\mathcal C(kA,B) = \mathcal C(A,B)\operatorname{diag}(I_m,kI_m,\dots,k^{n-1}I_m).
$$
For any scalar $k > 0$, $W_c(1; kA,B) = \frac 1k W_c(k; A,B)$.

With that, we can conclude that the invertibility of $W_c(1; A,B)$ is equivalent to the invertibility of $W_c(k; A,B)$ for any scalar $k > 0$.
If you prefer, you could use the Hautus critereon instead of $\mathcal C(A,B)$: the input-state system $(A,B)$ is controllable if and only if $[\lambda I - A\ \  B]$ has full rank for all $\lambda \in \Bbb C$. For any scalar $k > 0$, this is equivalent to $[\lambda I - kA\ \ B]$ having full rank for all $\lambda$ since
$$
[\lambda I - kA\ \ B] = 
[k((\lambda/k) I - A)\ \ B] = 
[(\lambda/k) I - A\ \ B] \operatorname{diag}(kI_n, I_m).
$$
